# Searching deeper in response in local results (Semantic UI Search)

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui, userscripts

I'm grabbing results of a search from Anilist Graghql and am attempting to use Semantic-ui Search to search through the results. Unfortunately I have been unable to find a question here pertaining to my particular issue. I need to search in `result.title.english` but have been unable to do so constantly getting "No results". If there's a better live search to use with userscripts let me know.

data.data.Page.media is the results shown below.

```
        type: 'category',
        source : data.data.Page.media,
        apiSettings: {
            onResponse: function(myfunc) {
                var response = data.data.Page.media
                $.each(myfunc, function(index, item) {
                    var category = item.format.toUpperCase() || 'Unknown',
                        maxResults = 10;
                    if (index >= maxResults) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (response.results[category] === undefined) {
                        response.results[category] = {
                            name: '~~~~~~~~~~' + category + '~~~~~~~~~~',
                            results: []
                        };
                    }
                    var Name = item.title.english + ' (' + item.tear + ')';
                    response.results[category].results.push({
                        title: Name,
                        description: '',
                    });
                });
                return response;
            }
        },
        fields: {
            results: 'results',
            title: 'name'
        },
        minCharacters: 3
    })
```

This is the results from Anilist

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UluWl.png

```js
    var timer = null;
    $('#searchID').keyup(() => {clearTimeout(timer);timer = setTimeout(() => aniSearch(), 1000);});;

function aniSearch() {
 var query = `query ($searchTerm:String){
      Page{
        media(search: $searchTerm, type: ANIME) {
          id,
          title {
            romaji
            english
            native
          },
          type,
          startDate {
            year
          },
          endDate {
            year
            month
            day
          }
          episodes,
          chapters,
          duration,
          averageScore,
          popularity,
          description,
          coverImage {
            large
          },
          genres,
          bannerImage,
          trailer {
            id
          },
          siteUrl,
          volumes,
          format,
        }
      }
    }
`;
 var variables = {
  searchTerm: document.getElementById('searchID').value
 };
    var url = 'https://graphql.anilist.co',
    options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: query,
            variables: variables
        })
    };

// Make the HTTP Api request
fetch(url, options).then(handleResponse)
                   .then(handleData)
                   .catch(handleError);
}

function handleResponse(response) {
    return response.json().then(function (json) {
        return response.ok ? json : Promise.reject(json);
    });
}

function handleError(error) {
    alert('Error, check console');
    console.error(error);
}
    function handleData(data) {
    var titleSearch = data.data.Page.media;
    $('#anilist_search').search({
  type: 'category',
        source : data.data.Page.media,
  apiSettings: {
   onResponse: function(myfunc) {
    var response = data.data.Page.media
    $.each(myfunc, function(index, item) {
     var category = item.format.toUpperCase() || 'Unknown',
      maxResults = 10;
     if (index >= maxResults) {
      return false;
     }
     if (response.results[category] === undefined) {
      response.results[category] = {
       name: '~~~~~~~~~~' + category + '~~~~~~~~~~',
       results: []
      };
     }
     var Name = item.title.english + ' (' + item.tear + ')';
     response.results[category].results.push({
      title: Name,
      description: '',
     });
    });
    return response;
   }
  },
  fields: {
   results: 'results',
   title: 'name'
  },
  minCharacters: 3
 });}
```

```css
@mediascreenand(min-width:300px){
/*Buttons*/
button[name=templateButton]{
background-color:#4caf50;
color:white;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:600;
padding:4px;
cursor:pointer;
outline:none;
margin-right:8px;
border:none;
border-radius:3px;
border-color:#67bd6a;
margin-top:5px;
box-shadow:002px0rgba(0,0,0,0.14),
02px2px0rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
01px3px0rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
}
@mediascreenand(min-width:768px){
/*Buttons*/
button[name=templateButton]{
background-color:#4caf50;
color:white;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:600;
padding:6px;
cursor:pointer;
outline:none;
margin-right:8px;
border:none;
border-radius:3px;
border-color:#67bd6a;
margin-top:5px;
box-shadow:002px0rgba(0,0,0,0.14),
02px2px0rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
01px3px0rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Semantic-Org/UI-Api/master/api.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Semantic-Org/UI-Search/master/search.js"></script>
<div id="AnilistGenerator">
<div class="ui search" id="anilist_search">
<input type="text" class="prompt input" id="searchID" placeholder="Anime English Title" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Anime English Title'">
<div class="results input" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is possible that you can add working example for interact with it? - Please see [mre] for more information.

Comment: I've attempted to add it here. Unfortunetly it seems the codesnippet doesnt work well with semantic UI

Comment: Thank you for take the suggestion. Are you familiar with jsfiddle? - if so, you can also use that tool for create a [mre]. another similar tools are CodeOpen.

Comment: I'm very new to JS :/ 
I've integrated the code into this webpage and posted the userscript code here.
https://pastebin.com/LZZupDEc
It shows in the top right of the page with the placehold "Anime English Title"